# Multiple image attachment generating error in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, email

I'm trying to attach multiple images in an email and these attachments are sent correctly but leaving an error message with:

Unable to locate the following email attachment: 
Unable to locate the following email attachment: 
220 smtp.googlemail.com ESMTP j12sm3168737pff.148 - gsmtp

//save files in database table
                      if ($_FILES['files']['name']) {

```
                      $DbArray = getDbArray("maintenanceimages");
                      $DBdata = $DbArray['dbdata'];

                      $filesCount = count($_FILES['files']['name']);

                      for($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++) {

                          $_FILES['file']['name']     = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
                          $_FILES['file']['type']     = $_FILES['files']['type'][$i];
                          $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
                          $_FILES['file']['error']     = $_FILES['files']['error'][$i];
                          $_FILES['file']['size']     = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];

                          // File upload configuration
                          $uploadPath = ASSETS_DIR . 'admin/img/maintenance/';
                          $config['upload_path'] = $uploadPath;
                          $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';

                          // Load and initialize upload library
                          $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                          $this->upload->initialize($config);

                          // Upload file to server
                          if($this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
                              // Uploaded file data
                              $Images[] = $this->upload->data();

                              $DBdata['ImageName'] = $_FILES['file']['name'];
                              $DBdata['ImagePath'] = $config['upload_path'];
                              $DBdata['ImageSize'] = $_FILES['file']['size'];
                              $DBdata['MaintenanceId'] = $id;
                              $Images[] = $_FILES['file'];
                              save("maintenanceimages", $DBdata);

                          }

                      }
                  }







                //send email
                  $config = Array(
                      'protocol' => 'smtp',
                      'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
                      'smtp_port' => 465,
                      'smtp_user' => 'abc@gmail.com',
                      'smtp_pass' => 'abc'
                  );

                  $this->load->library('email',$config);
                  $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

                  // attachment
                  foreach($Images as $image)
                  {
                      $this->email->attach($image['full_path']);
                  }

                  $this->email->from("abc@gmail.com");
                  $this->email->to("abc@gmail.com");
                  $this->email->subject("Maintenance complain");
                  $this->email->message($this->input->post('FullName') ." has submitted a Maintenance complain");


                  if($this->email->send())
                  {
                      echo "Your email was sent.!";
                  } else {
                      show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
                  }
```

Comment: if i were you i would do a test without the email part, and `print_r($Images)` and then manually check to see if each image exists on the server.

Comment: then we are brothers of different mothers. I did the same and verily the images are there.

Comment: As i removed the show_error code, it stopped generating error.

Comment: cool. did you check to see if your email got sent correctly with the attachments? if so, all good ;)

Comment: Yes brother, the email were being sent correctly with attachments and no error is being generated. I just wonder why did it generate error every time when I un comment the show_error code.

Comment: the codeigniter email library sucks imo. i use this: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/

Comment: I do also use PHP Mailer but sometimes on a free version of hosting, this library doesn't often seem to work.